# How to assembleDist a Gradle's test suite?

Tags: gradle

Suppose I have a basic Java app and there is an additional specific test suite for integration testing (defined in Gradle with [`testing{suites{...}}` DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#sec:declare_an_additional_test_suite)). I would like to package and distribute this test suite as a standalone self-contained thing with `org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher` as a `Main-Class`, and which will only need a JRE for running.

If you have a basic java-app, Gradle's `applcation` plugin [provides you a convenient set of tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks) to package your `src/main` code + dependencies into a single tar/zip with `bin`+`libs` folders. So, you will get a single self-contained package archived into tar/zip, and you will only need JRE to run it. These tasks are named `distTar`/`distZip` for producing `tar`/`zip` correspondingly, or there is also an `assembleDist` to produce both types of archive at once.

How can I create my own `distSpecificTestSuite(Tar|Zip)` task which will package only the test suite I need + it's dependencies into a single self-contained distributable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem. So, suppose my custom test suite (`testIntegration`) is declared as follows:

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    `jvm-test-suite`
}

testing {
    @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
    suites {
        val integrationTestSuite = register<JvmTestSuite>("testIntegration") {
            description = "Runs integration tests."
            testType.set("integration")

            useJUnitJupiter()
            dependencies {
                runtimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console-standalone")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in order to produce executable "distribution" out of this custom test suite and to do it the native Gradle way, I create additional tasks (similar to the ones, which `application` plugin provides out of the box for `src/main` code) and declare a custom `distribution` as follows:

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    `jvm-test-suite`
    distribution // <-- adding plugin for `distributions {...}` DSL
}

val packageIntegrationTestsJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    archiveFileName.set("integration-tests.jar")
    from(sourceSets.findByName("testIntegration")!!.output)
    destinationDirectory.set(File(project.buildDir, "libs-integration-tests"))
}

val integrationTestsStartScripts by tasks.registering(CreateStartScripts::class) {
    description = "Creates OS specific scripts to run integration tests as a JVM application."
    classpath = packageIntegrationTestsJar.get().outputs.files + sourceSets.findByName("testIntegraion")!!
        .runtimeClasspath
    mainClass.set("org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher")
    applicationName = "integration-tests"
    outputDir = File(project.buildDir, "scripts")
}

distributions {
    create("integrationTests") {
        distributionBaseName.set("integration-tests")
        version = ""
        contents {
            from(sourceSets.findByName("testIntegration")!!.runtimeClasspath){
                include("*.jar")
                into("lib")
            }
            from(packageIntegrationTestsJar) {
                into("lib")
            }
            from(integrationTestsStartScripts) {
                into("bin")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above `distributions` configuration creates the following additional tasks for you: `integrationTestsDistZip`/`distTar`/`distJar` and `installIntegrationTestsDist`

As a result, Gradle will prepare a "distribution" for you, which will contain `bin` and `lib` folders. All jars (including `integration-tests.jar` itself) are placed into `lib`, and `bin` contains windows/unix scripts for running test suite on your default JVM with all the necessary classpath from `lib`